# Prove that $ \int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{\cos (x)} \cos (\sin (x))}{x^2+1} \, dx = \frac{\pi}{2} e^{1/e} $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

This is given as an exercise in an old calculus textbook from the 20s.
What is the best way to tackle this?
The value is around $2.269278970$

Comment: The numerator is the real part if $e^{e^{ix}}$ but I don’t know if or how that helps.

Comment: It would help to give the level of the calculus book. Does it include complex analysis? What has been covered so far?

Comment: It's from Edwards' Integral Calculus. Complex analysis has not been introduced yet. The chapter this is included in is about series substitution and rearrangements.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your efforts at answering the question so that others can build on what you've already done.

Comment: Maybe use that $\cos z=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$, so $$\cos\sin x=\frac{e^{i\sin x}+e^{i\sin x}}{2}$$ so $$e^{\cos x}\cos\sin x=\frac{e^{\cos x+i\sin x}+e^{\cos x-i\sin x}}{2}=\frac{e^{e^{ix}}+e^{e^{-ix}}}{2}$$I don't know if this can help

Comment: Okay, that helped a lot. I figured it out. Thanks guys. Should I delete the question or leave it standing?

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer.

Comment: Post your own answer. @DecarbonatedOdes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note

\begin{align}
I= & \int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{\cos (x)} \cos (\sin (x))}{x^2+1} \, dx \\
= & Re \int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{e^{ix}} }{x^2+1} \, dx 
= Re \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{k!}\int_0^{\infty } \frac{{e^{i kx}} }{x^2+1} \, dx 
=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{k!} \int_0^{\infty } \frac{\cos kx}{x^2+1} \, dx \\
\end{align}
Then, apply the known result $\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\cos kx}{x^2+1} \, dx 
=\frac\pi2 e^{-k}$ to obtain
$$I = \frac\pi2 \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{k!}e^{-k} =\frac{\pi}{2} e^{1/e} 
$$

Answer (score 2):

Noting the expansion given in the comments above we can see that
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(k \cdot x)}{k!} = e^{\cos(x)} \cdot \cos(\sin(x))$$

Recalling that
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^2+1} dx = \frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_k}{e^k} \\
f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k \cdot \cos(k \cdot x)$$
Therefore $a_k = \frac{1}{k!} $ gives the required result.